# Stardate and Other dates on FREE version of Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

newbie here.

A 'Stardate' question here:

I am creating an offbeat news site 'thedailyplanetonline.wordpress.com' using the free version of Wordpress, and would like to put something in the top widget bar that calculates and displays a Star Trek Stardate, Julian and Gregorian Dates, Mayan dates, and so on.

Since Javascript has no 'easy way' of working with the free version, do you have any advice or crafty suggestions on how to get this to work?

At the moment its not possible to buy a upgrade

And again. Keep in mind this is the free version of Wordpress.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: "Since Javascript has no 'easy way' of working with the free version" - sounds unlikely to me. Reference?

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't an answer you'd want to hear, but wordpress.com hosted sites most likely cannot do this for you, unless you find a WordPress.com theme that already does this.

The free, hosted version of WordPress does not allow you to add your own themes or plugins, or modify existing themes. You are given a small set of allowed themes and allowed plugins.

If you wanted to have something more custom, you will need to look into self-hosted Wordpress instead. That means either setting up your own web server (only recommended if you know what you're doing), or set up web hosting.

For more information on the limitations of Wordpress.com sites, please see this link:

http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/what-are-the-limitations-of-wordpress-com/

and if you do go the hosted route, here's a helpful article on migrating your Wordpress.com site:

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-properly-move-your-blog-from-wordpress-com-to-wordpress-org/

Comment: Again, no money means I need alternate solutions and creative ideas here using what I am offered. 

Now a couple ideas I have had have been: To link to an external 'image' that generates the information dynamically on the image itself. That's a no brainer and doesn't require me to 'pay for more'. 

But then I am left trying to find a place to host that image generation code. Any advice?

Another idea I had was an IFORM or other tags that wordpress may not filter to not filter the javascript. Now I was hoping someone else had 'blazed' this trail already.

It cant be done is not an answer. Sorry

Comment: And keep in mind. Limitations are mere perceptual limitations. Stack Overflow has always seemed to elicit thoughtful intuitive responses from clever programmers who don't always follow the pay per scheme. But I am thinking I may be the only coder left in the world who doesn't take 'it can't be done without money' as an appropriate response.